# Ralink Corp dwa 525 n 150 wireless adapter not working on 14.04

Tags: networking

I am new to Ubuntu.
I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Acer Veriton M200.

The laptop has a Ralink Corp dwa 525 n 150 wireless adapter, which is not working on my Ubuntu installation, but works flawlessly on my Windows 8.1 installation

When I use:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
```

it shows that it already have installed 'rt2800pci' driver in it and when I run:

```
rfkill list all
```

it shows neither soft or hard block.

I have other Devices with the same OS installed, and they also show the same response to both commands but wifi is working pretty nicely in them.

I have used

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 up 
sudo service network-manager restart 
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: You asked the same question a few days ago. Why not continue in your original thread?? https://askubuntu.com/questions/986272/how-to-install-ralink-corp-dwa-525-n-150-wireless-adapter-pci-rv-a-2-in-ubuntu-1

Comment: Sorry. I could but now please solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

14.04 Is an old version. If you have driver issues, you should update.

I'd recommend 16.04 LTS. Install it by following this:

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#0

Comment: I can't update. This PC is provided by my department and I have to use this os .

Comment: The OS stays the same though. If it is working on other devices, the hardware may be faulty.

Comment: No, In win 8.1installed on the same pc, it is working

Comment: Have you tried running sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Oh common, is upgrading the only solution

Comment: I'm no Linux nerd. There may be other solutions, but 99% of the time updating solves most issues.

Comment: Hey, I have upgraded but still the problem is not solved

Comment: Hey, I tried to upgrade but when I log in, the log in screen comes again. I was unable to login and a new problem raised. So I had to reinstall the older version.